# How to check if dpkg-architecture --list has all the architectures?

Tags: wine, dpkg, skype, 32-bit

To install skype and dependencies on 16.04. 64bit I need to

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Via ([`man page`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/dpkg-architecture.1.html)):

```
dpkg-architecture --list
```

I then can check the list of architectures. What line must be in there to be sure that the first command was executed correctly?

My problem is that I cannot install Skype and I suspect the architecture was not updated correctly. I also suspect this might somehow relate to my installation of Wine.

Comment: No, you don't need that. Skype is multiarched these days, and the need to explicitly add the 32 bit architecture is history since long ago.

Comment: My problem was due to some failure during a previously done upgrade to 16.04 and has been solved.

Answer (score 29):

I answer my own question because I just found out via

```
dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
```

which printed

```
i386
```

that obviously multiarch is/was enabled.

Comment: Althogh it is an old discussion, I would like to add more info in case it can help others: in order to see all available architecture to add to your machine, issue the command "dpkg-architecture --list-known"